# Chaining trigger after $(document).on()

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

When binding an event to an element the old way, chaining a trigger right after declaring the binding was easy:

```
$('#button').click(...).trigger('click');
```

But I'm binding my events like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() { ... });
```

And attaching `.trigger('click')` would obviously not target my specific element. Is there any way to solve this with a one liner instead of having to use:

```
$('#button').trigger('click');
```

on a separate line right after?

Comment: why should you need to use `$(document).on('click', '#button',`

Answer (score 1):

You can find and trigger on the document.

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() { ... })
    .find('#button').trigger('click');
```

`$(document).on('click', '#button', function(){})` is not needed in your case because it is only needed if elements are dynamically added. If dynamically added, we cannot trigger the click.

So you can simply do the first option from your question.

```
$('#button').click(...).trigger('click');
```

or you can use

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){ } ).trigger('click');
```